# Saxon 9.2 / Java / XSLT: setting transformer parameters using setParameters()

Tags: java, xslt, saxon, transformer-model

I have the following XSLT 2.0 template:

```
<xsl:template name="t1">
<xsl:variable name="totalpos" as="xsd:double" select="$currentTotal"/>
..
```

I am struggling to programmatticaly provide `currentTotal` as a parameter to the transformer, like this:

```
transformer.setParameter("currentTotal", new Double("100"))
```

.. but without any positive results:

> Error at /xsl:transform/xsl:template[3]/xsl:variable[1]    XPST0008:
>   XPath syntax error at char 13 on line -1 in {$currentTotal}:
>       Variable $currentTotal has not been declared

When calling `setParameter()`, the `currentTotal` variable will also get defined, right?
How should I invoke the `setParameter()` call so that the `currentTotal` defined in my application will be seen inside the style-sheet?

For clarification, I am instantiating the transformer like this:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
transformerFactory = new TransformerFactoryImpl();
transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(inputNodes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters have to be declared in your stylesheet using

```
<xsl:param name="currentTotal"/>
```

inside the `xsl:stylesheet` element. You can also define a default value with the `select` attribute or inside the element body.

Comment: Indeed, I need to define the variable. I was expecting that it will be defined when I setParameter, but I was wrong. 
Sorry for my late check, I was on vacation. 

Thanks!