# Providing parameters to XSLT program using Java API

Tags: java, xslt, saxon, transformer-model

What I want to do is:

```
setParameter(String name, String value)
```

But the API is:

```
void setParameter(QName name, XdmValue value)
```

I can't find any example to properly create XdmValue and QName, [examples I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434644/saxon-9-2-java-xslt-setting-transformer-parameters-using-setparameters) are all using different versions of this function/api.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very often parameters have names that are in no namespace, so you can construct the QName using the constructor `new QName("p")`. If the parameter value is a string, you can construct the value using `new XdmAtomicValue("value")`. So your example reduces to

```
setParameter(new QName(name), new XdmAtomicValue(value))
```

In designing an API like this, one has to judge carefully how to balance the simplicity that comes from providing "shortcut" methods for common simple cases, versus the complexity that comes from having zillions of methods. So I provided `new QName(string)`, but I didn't provide `setParameter(string, string)`.

Comment: am using the s9api now and am glad to see the new setParameter has an xdmvalue param, and i also noticed all notice valuerepresentations ... though i am trying to wrap my head around passing more complex types into xsl, for now i am just going to use atomicvalues

Comment: An XdmNode is an XdmValue, so you can also pass an XdmNode. If you want to pass a sequence of items, XdmValue has a constructor that accepts a collection of XdmItem: each XdmItem can be an XdmAtomicValue or an XdmNode.

Comment: i guess in the xsl you assign the param to a variable and access the values in the xdmnode using xpath $xdmnodeparm/pathtosomexml

Comment: Sure, the parameter is just a variable whose value is a node.

Comment: thanks. because my source xml document was dynamic in the servlet i ended up passing all the session and doc information in that way for now